# Why expected route does not add item to models collection using sails.js blueprint API

Tags: javascript, api, rest, sails.js, blueprint

Quick question for anyone that can help relating to adding an item to a models collection. (eg: Adding a tag to a blog post. Many to Many relationship) Doing this through a REST API call with default blueprints.

This works: http://host/blogpost/1/tag/add/2

however I would expect this to work: http://host/blogpost/1/tag/2

Instead it gives a 404 not found.

Thanks
Spencer

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to @japel in the sails chat room for pointing out that there is no route for the second option. In fact now that I think about it, how else would the blueprint know if I want to add or remove an item without specifying the keyword, although perhaps changing from a POST to a DELETE could work. The comments in the docs for the blueprint API add method are somewhat misleading: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/add-to

For now I can live with specifying the action in the route.